# modify same entity from different threads greendao

Tags: android, multithreading, greendao

i am about to develop an android app using greendao where same business entities can be modified either by the user or by a background thread (updates of the entity received from the server).
How are the two threads "informed" when trying to modify the object if the other transaction already have changed the same entity? Will there be an exception thrown (e.g. AlreadyChanged).
Is there a bestpractice using greendao in such a scenario?

Thanks.